# Xcode- store data in Core Data or SQLite?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, core-data

I am using Xcode 4.3-If I'm trying to store user's location (latitude and longitude) in a database and update their location to the database let's says every 30 meters they travel, would it be better to use core data or SQLite? Currently I am using core data and I'm having alot of trouble with it. I need to decide whether I need to make the switch and solely use SQLite. Any advice? *Note: The user does NOT need to see their own location data on the phone

Answer (score 2):

Your "trouble" with core data suggests that you aren't very familiar with that API. On iOS, by default, core data uses sqlite as the underlying persistent store for it's data anyway, so in your case it's probaply not a matter of performance and nitty gritty stuff, but rather understanding the concepts. If you feel more comfortable and "at home" dealing with sqlite directly or using thirdparty sqlite objecitive-c wrapper frameworks, stick with that, get the job done. Out of the box, what core data gives you for free is a higher level of abstraction when dealing with data (it's all about objects and predicates, basically, and some helpers to bind data to your views) and memory management. The downside is, you have to teaxh yourself all that stuff, and it will crash on you all over the place if you get it wrong, so RTFM. Core Data: Once you have the expertise, it's heaven, but the way to expertise is a steep learning curve.

You want an advice to stick with direct sqlite access because you feel you can handle that? Go.

If you have time to teach yourself how Core Data works, why it's not a relational db etc, go, it's worth it and will make your developer's live much easier.

Answer (score 0):

While they are both legitimate applications to what you are trying to do, the important difference between SQLite and CoreData is that SQLite can be relational.  If you need a relational table then I would say a switch can be rationalized, but if you have a simple denormalized data collection, you should be fine with CoreData. If anything setting up SQLite for your iOS application is relatively simple and worth a try.

More information can be found here: [when-to-use-sqlite-instead-of-core-data-on-the-iphone/](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1959-when-to-use-sqlite-instead-of-core-data-on-the-iphone/)